count the number of yes in long data
I have a data frame in a long data form. The value of variable pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al could be 2 (No), 1 (Yes) or NA. I want to count the percentage of pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al==1 in each year out of the total number of rows. However, if I use mean(), it doesn't count the NAs and I'm getting 100% in some years.
vbid_nodup_merged_filtered %>%
  select(Year, VBID, pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al) %>%
  arrange(Year) %>%
  add_count(Year) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al = ifelse(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(percent_yes = 100*mean(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  slice(1)-> vbid_unlimited_percent


Please run dput(vbid_nodup_merged_filtered) and copy/paste the output into your edited post. If the data is large, provide a smaller sample.

Most of your commands are unnecessary. Try just: summarise(vbid_nodup_merged_filtered, percent_yes=100*mean(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al==1, na.rm = TRUE), .by=Year) |> arrange(Year)

@Edward I like you code! But it's still not counting the NAs

You can replace NA with another value, say 3, and then summarise:
vbid_nodup_merged_filtered |>
  mutate(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al=replace_na(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al, value=3)) |>
  summarise(percent_yes=100*mean(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al==1, na.rm=TRUE), .by=Year) |>
  arrange(Year)

Note: no data supplied. Another option is to use mean_(.) from the hablar package.

You could maybe change
mutate(percent_yes = 100 * mean(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al, na.rm = TRUE))

to
mutate(percent_yes = 100 * sum(pbp_b10b_bendesc_lim_al, na.rm = TRUE) / n())

